# Java - JUnit - testing methods - MultipleMarkersError

Tags: java, class, testing, methods, junit

I have just started learning JUnit testing. I have to write test for methoods below. I started from testting zero(). Can you tell me what i do wrongly there? And leave some helpful examples how should i test rest of this methods?

```
private Accumulator a;
int acc;

public void test() 
    {
        Kalkulator test = new Kalkulator();
        int result = test.zero(); // my error: MULTIPLE MARKERS
        assertEquals(0,result);
    }

// Methoods

public void setAccumulator( Accumulator a ){
    this.a = a;
    acc = a.get();
}

public Accumulator getAccumulator(){    
    return a;
}

public int get(){
        return acc;
}

public void zero(){
    acc = 0;
}

//***get***
public int get() 
{
         return acc;      
}
```

Comment: What is it doing?  What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't set result to test.zero() because zero() has a void return type.
2. If you want to test something using JUnit, you need to annotate the method you're testing with @Test.
3. In test(), you should change assertEquals() to Assert.assertEquals().
4. Take a look at the JUnit Assert API. http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html